# Drupal 7 Header & Footer give title

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I'm using drupal 7.

When u install this on home page it's giving Home, About Us pages links.

```
<a class="active" href="/drupal/">Home</a>
```

I would like to give title here like this but it's drupal core how can i do so it get below output.

```
<a class="active" href="/drupal/" title="Home">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module.

It allows you to add title, id, css classes and few more attributes to the anchor tag.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.